# Shared authentication with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have two Rails 4 sites, auth.example.com and app.example.com. Eventually there are going to be multiple app-type sites, maybe a dozen or two, but let's start with the one. Auth has devise set up so we can do basic user management (user creation and deactivation, password and SSH key management, etc.), with users logging into auth so they can do basic stuff themselves like update their address or phone number.

I want to set up app so that it uses the same authentication as auth. If a user tries to access app without being logged in, I want to redirect them to auth so they can log in, then go back to the page they were trying to access on app. Basically, I want to do devise actions on app, but with devise residing on auth. This, of course, is so that when we have multiple sites running, we can implement devise once instead of having to put it on every one of our sites individually.

I found this but it doesn't look like it's quite what I want:

http://4trabes.com/2012/10/31/remote-authentication-with-devise/

Anybody have a pointer to a resource that can walk me through how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a small API simply for user management. Then allow your other apps to make calls to that API to log a user in, create a user, etc. So keeping them on whatever site they're on, but in the background you're talking to the auth API.